# Possible way to combine to methods that use duplicate code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two methods `getTargetComponentById` and `getTargetComponentByName` which perform a lookup on an object based on a particular key and returns an object. The two methods work fine seperated, but I would like to combine them to cut down on duplicated code. What would be the best way of combining them:

```
  getTargetComponentById(componentId: string): IComponentTarget[] {
    const targetComponents = [];
    const website = this.website.getValue();
    for (let i = 0; i < website.pages.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < website.pages[i].components.length; j++) {
        if (website.pages[i].components[j].componentId === componentId) {
          targetComponents.push({
            activePageIndex: i,
            activeComponentIndex: j,
          });
        }
      }
    }
    return targetComponents;
  }

  getTargetComponentByName(componentName: string, activeWebsite = null): IComponentTarget[] {
    let website: IWebsite;
    if (activeWebsite === null) {
      website = this.website.getValue();
    } else {
      website = activeWebsite;
    }
    const targetComponents = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < website.pages.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < website.pages[i].components.length; j++) {
        if (website.pages[i].components[j].componentName === componentName) {
          targetComponents.push({
            activePageIndex: i,
            activeComponentIndex: j,
          });
        }
      }
    }
    return targetComponents;
  }
```

Comment: `getTargetComponentById(componentId: string, activeWebsite = null)`, `const website = activeWebsite || this.website.getValue();`, then you only have to find a way how to distinguish an id from a name.

Comment: This better fits https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the property to use as an extra input parameter.

```
getTargetComponentByProperty(property: 'componentName' | 'componentId', value: string, activeWebsite ?= null): IComponentTarget[] {
  const website: IWebsite = activeWebsite ? activeWebsite : this.website.getValue();
  const targetComponents = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < website.pages.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < website.pages[i].components.length; j++) {
      if (website.pages[i].components[j][property] === value) {
        targetComponents.push({
          activePageIndex: i,
          activeComponentIndex: j,
        });
      }
    }
  }
  return targetComponents;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use bracket notation instead of dot notation property accessor to generalize the statement `website.pages[i].components[j].componentName === componentName`. Try the following

```js
getTargetComponent(component: string, activeWebsite ?= null): IComponentTarget[] {
  const website: IWebsite = activeWebsite ? activeWebsite : this.website.getValue();
  const targetComponents = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < website.pages.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < website.pages[i].components.length; j++) {
      if (website.pages[i].components[j][component] === component) {        // <-- bracket notation here
        targetComponents.push({
          activePageIndex: i,
          activeComponentIndex: j,
        });
      }
    }
  }
  return targetComponents;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this

```
getTargetComponent(arg: string|number, activeWebsite ?= null): IComponentTarget[] {
  const website = activeWebsite || this.website.getValue();
  if (''+arg===arg)
      console.log("arg is a string")
  else
      console.log("arg is a number")

 //well, you can use
 const field=(''+arg===arg)?'componentName':'componentId'
 //and use components[j][field]==arg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expose two different interface methods that internally use only one method for logic.
I think this is the most elegant way of doing it.
If you are using angular (and therefore typescript) you can also enter the two methods as public and the core method as private.

```
  public getTargetComponentById(id: string): IComponentTarget[] {
    return getTargetComponentBy(id, null, 'componentId');
  }

  public getTargetComponentByName(name: string, activeWebsite = null): IComponentTarget[] {
    return getTargetComponentBy(name, activeWebsite, 'componentName');
  }

  private getTargetComponentBy(componentKey: string, activeWebsite = null, prop: string): IComponentTarget[] {
    let website: IWebsite;
    if (activeWebsite === null) {
      website = this.website.getValue();
    } else {
      website = activeWebsite;
    }
    const targetComponents = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < website.pages.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < website.pages[i].components.length; j++) {
        const aComp = website.pages[i].components[j];
        if (website.pages[i].components[j][prop] === componentKey) {
          targetComponents.push({
            activePageIndex: i,
            activeComponentIndex: j,
          });
        }
      }
    }
    return targetComponents;
  }
```